# How to write a linq Query for Retrieving Productimages from entity model for the selected PriceRange?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all i have a Entity model ProdcutTable in my MVC4 WebApi application which has the following column names

```
  [ProductID] [ProductName] [ProductDescritpion] [Price] [ImageURL] and so on
```

now i have to pass the price range as parameters 
example

```
     frstvale=$200
     SecoundVal=$500
```

i have to retrive the [ProductID] [ProductName] [ProductDescritpion] [Price] [ImageURL] from the ProdcutTable for the selected price range how can i write the linq query for this at present i am retrieving all images from the table via a ajax call now i have to pass the paramaters for the price to my method and retrieve the records for the selected price range can any one help in writing the query for this

```
    this is my model


     public class Products
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName{get;set;}
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductColor { get; set;}
    public string ProductSize { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public string DetailsURL { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Firstvalue { get; set; }
    public string Lastvalue { get; set; }
}
```

this is how i am retrieving all my images

```
    private ProductsEntities products = new ProductsEntities();
     public IEnumerable<ProductTable> GetAllProdcuts()
    {
        return products.ProductTables.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Where` extension method that takes an expression as parameter to filter out the return objects.

```
private ProductsEntities products = new ProductsEntities();
public IEnumerable<ProductTable> GetAllProdcuts()
{
    return products.ProductTables.Where(x=>x.Price>firstPrice && x.Price<secondPrice).AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: i am geting an error at where saying doesn't contain a definition for where

Comment: its `Where` w with capital letter did you try this

Comment: Ok, i have updated the answer with capital `W`, if it solves your problem, accept the answer as this question is open since a long time

Comment: now i am getting error after the Where sayinf 'Delegate'system.Func<Products.Models.ProdcutTable,int bool> does not take 1 arguments''